# How to open a random folder within a directory

Tags: python, random, cmd, directory

I was wondering how I would use a batch file or Python to open a random folder from a selection of many folders within a directory?

Comment: 1) get list of all folder within a directory 2) random.choice(<list of folders>) 3) open directory 4) PROFIT!

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by opening a folder?

Comment: Sorry I meant a batch file

Comment: @coirius - really? It should be 4) ... 5) PROFIT! The "..." is the most important step of all!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
>>> import os
>>> files = os.listdir('/tmp')
>>> dirs = [f for f in files if os.path.isdir(f)]
>>> random.sample(dirs,1)
['tempdir']
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd` you could do it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set root=C:\base\folder

for /f %%d in ('dir /b /a:d "%root%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%%d

set /a num=%RANDOM% %% %count%

for /f "skip=%num% tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /a:d "%root%"') do (
  set folder=%%~fd
  goto :FIN
)

:FIN
echo %folder%

endlocal
```